# Will this code add hash-part to Lua array-like table?

Tags: arrays, lua

Lua code

```
local var = {} 

for i = 1, 10000, 1 do
    table.insert ( var, i )
end

var[5] = { some = false, another = 2 }
var[888] = @userdata
var[10000] = {}
var[1] = 1
var[1] = false
```

1 ) After this, is **var** still only with array-part, or it has hash-part too?

2 ) Does code

```
var[10001] = 1
```

add hash-part to **var** or it only forces table rehash without adding hash-part ?

3) How it affects on size of table?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you so interested in this? Some table functions needs sequences, but other than that, how a table is implemented shouldn't be a problem in general. Is there any practical reason?

Comment: @yu-hao I am using Lua tables to intensive transfer data between users. Size is important. And it is a good thing save some CPU with no rehash every table every value assign. Tables without hash-part and without rehashing are ideal for my aims.

Answer (score 1):

The table will only have an array part after both 1 and 2. The reason is that you have a contiguous set of indices. Specifically, you created entries from 1 to 10,001 and Lua will have allocated space for them.

If for example, you had created 1 to 1000 then added 10001, it would have added the last one in the hash part rather than create nil entries for all the entries between.

It doesn't matter what type of data you put in as the value for the entries, Lua is only interested in the indices when deciding between array and hash. The exception here is setting values to `nil`. This can get a bit complicated but if table space is your primary concern, I don't believe Lua ever reduces the array an hash parts if you nil sets of them out. I could be mistaken on this.

As to the size, Lua uses a doubling strategy. So, after you hit entry 8192, Lua added another 8192 so there was no extra array space created between 10000 and 10001.

BTW Lua doesn't rehash every table addition. When it adds buckets, it gives itself some headroom. I believe it doubles there too. Note, if your data is sparse i.e. you aren't going to fill most of the indices between 1 and your max, then this approach to hashing can be very beneficial for space even if your indices are numbers. The main downside is it means you can't use `ipairs` across all your entries.

Comment: Note that this is all implementation-dependent behavior. It may work differently in LuaJIT, LuaJ, etc.

Comment: Regarding the size: There is [lua-getsize](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-getsize) (original code [here](http://code.matthewwild.co.uk/lua-getsize/)), so you can measure yourself. Works for PUC-Rio Lua only, though.

Comment: It is indeed implementation dependent. On the plus side lua, luajit and luaj all implement this piece with very similar behaviour. You might get an off by one difference when the doubling occurs but otherwise they're pretty consistent. That's not to say you should rely too heavily on this fact. The absolute sidings may differ substantially.